# UIAlertView issue in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

After upgrading to iOS9 my `UIAlertview` or `UIAlertcontroller` doesn't show the alert, only the transparent black background that comes with it!

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong!. Below iOS 9 versions everything is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Please use UIAlertViewController instead of UIAlertView because it is depricated.

Comment: Add also your code to show this alert please.

Comment: I think you mean `UIAlertController` Dharmbir.

Comment: please share your codes

Comment: Curious though. `UIAlertView` is still running fine on my older apps even with iOS 9.

Comment: [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"User authorization failed with message: %@", errorResponse.error.message] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

Comment: @NSNoob Yes, UIAlertView working fine but in some case its happening that's why i suggested him.

Comment: On my live app its working fine too but after compiling it with xcode 7 then mine or third party sdks alertview is showing like this

Answer (score 1):

I am using this piece of code for showing UIAlertView
and it's working fine for me,

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" 
    message:@"" 
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"" 
    otherButtonTitles:@"", ..., nil];

    [alert show];
```

Comment: even-though this is working for me as well in ios 9, wii this prevent my app from being accepted in the app store? given that UIAlertview is depreciated in ios 8.0 +

Answer (score 0):

May be some thing is already working on main thread so that alert view is not visible.Please try this

```
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ 

alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reload data ?"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil]; 


 [alert show];

 }];
```